# Text in bootstrap text-well won't center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm trying to create a virtual roulette wheel.  Right now my concerns are strictly aesthetic.  In the text-well on the right, the number in the #chipsInv won't center, except when I put an html "center" tag, and then for some reason it creates a huge amount of empty space at the bottom.

Here is my code, I've left out the Javascript since I assume it's irrelevant:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #ball {
        position: absolute;
        left: 208px;
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        transition: top 1s;
    }
    
    #wheel {}
    
    form {}
    
    .row {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <img id="ball" src="ball.png" onclick="spin()"></img>
                <img id="wheel" src="Rwheelbg.png" onclick="spin()"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="well well-lg">
                    <span><center>Chips</center></span>
                    <br>
                    <span style="font-size: 180px; text-align: center;" id="chipsInv">10</span>
                    <!-- Why won't this center!? -->
                    <br>
                    <span style="float:right;" id="purchase"><a style = "color:green !important;" href = "#">$ Purchase More Chips?</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Row ends here -->
        </div>
        <p>Bet on:</p>
        <form action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="21" value="310" id="310"> 21
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="9" value="100" id="100"> 9
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="14" value="120" id="120"> 14
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="13" value="240" id="240"> 13
        </form>
        <p>Bet on up to four numbers. However, be warned, the more numbers you bet on, the lower your chip return will be.</p>
        <!-- container ends here -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what's the point of using boostrap if you don't use boostrap classes? `text-center` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/

Comment: Just add text-center class on the "well well-lg" div as Robert said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap, as best you can / where you can, use the Bootstrap classes to provide the styling you're looking for, as the Bootstrap classes are designed to be compatible with one another.

```
  <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="well well-lg">
        <div class="text-center">Chips</div>
        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 180px;" id="chipsInv">10</div>
        <div class="float-right" id ="purchase"><a style = "color:green !important;" href = "#">$ Purchase More Chips?</a></div>        
      </div>
  </div>
```

If you want to text center everything in your example you can simply add the text-center class next to your well well-lg classes, as follows :

```
  <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="well well-lg text-center">
            <div>Chips</div>
            <div style="font-size: 180px;" id="chipsInv">10</div>
            <div class="float-right" id ="purchase"><a style = "color:green !important;" href = "#">$ Purchase More Chips?</a></div>        
          </div>
  </div>
```

Additionally;

- with Bootstrap, they recommend you use div's where possible, and then
  you can specify different behaviour by modifying the classes of those
  divs, such as "d-inline", or "d-block". That was the reason I changed
  your spans to divs.
- Ensure your col-lg-6 div is contained within a div with class "row", and that according to the docs, these divs specifying col div when added together do not exceed 12. [Bootstrap Grid Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)